# Testing multiple conditions with a Python if statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to get into coding and this is kinda part of the assignments that i need to do to get into the classes.

> In this task, you will implement a check using the if… else structure you learned earlier.You are required to create a program that uses this conditional.
>
> At your school, the front gate is locked at night for safety. You often need to study late on campus. There is sometimes a night guard on duty who can let you in. You want to be able to check if you can access the school campus at a particular time.
>
> The current hour of the day is given in the range 0, 1, 2 … 23 and the guard’s presence is indicated by with a True/False boolean.
>
> If the hour is from 7 to 17, you do not need the guard to be there as the gate is open
> If the hour is before 7 or after 17, the guard must be there to let you in
> Using predefined variables for the hour of the day and whether the guard is present or not, write an if statement to print out whether you can get in.
>
> Example start:
> hour = 4
> guard = True
>
> Example output:
> 'You're in!'
>
> Make use of the if statement structure to implement the program.

One of my ideas was:

```
Time = int(input("Time of getting in: "))
open = 7
closed = 17
if Time > open and Time < closed:
    print("You can not enter")
```

Comment: What is your question? And by the way, don't use `open` as name, it's a built-in

Comment: So far you are doing pretty well. One thing to fix: `if Time > open and Time < closed:` means that `Time` is between the hours of `7` and `17`, which means it should print `You're in!`. Once you fix that, then just use `else:` to print out the other message and you're golden.

Comment: [Comparison expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) can be used, something like  
`if  open <= Time > closed:`

Technically speaking your proposed answer is not wrong but neither correct.
What would happen at 7 and at 17?

Comment: In addition to what @buran said, if anything here highlights as orange in Python it's a builtin so don't use it.

Comment: @CheTesta Do you mean `if  open <= Time < closed` ?

Comment: Remember that `<` and `>` do not include `=`. You need to use `>= open`.

Comment: To clarify the point made by @AER, don't use names highlighted in orange in your code listing (e.g. "open", "print", "input") as the name of a local variable.

Comment: Your idea is great. You just need to work on other procedures as in example.

Comment: Thanks all. I will ty do it again. There were just few lessons(generall ones) before this task and I have never tried to code before so it is really hard. :)

Comment: Did it! WIth your help obviously! thank you :)  Time = int(input("Time of getting in: "))
start = 7
finish = 17
if Time >= start and Time <= finish:
    print("You are in!")
else:
    print("You need the guard to let you in ;( ")

Answer (score 1):

cap O will solve

```
Time = int(input("Time of getting in: "))
Open = 7
closed = 17
if Time > Open and Time < closed:
    print("You can not enter")
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not too difficult, you can do a simple function like that :

```py
def go_to_study(hour, start_day = 7, end_day = 17):
    if (hour >= start_day and hour <= end_day):
        return True
    else:
        return False

    // on one line, uncomment if  you want.
    // return (hour >= start_day and hour <= end_day)
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
hour=int(input("Enter the Hour"))

if hour>=7 and hour<=17:
    print("You can Go")  
else:
    print("You need Guard to let you in")
```

Comment: Whitespace is important in Python. Please [edit] this answer and fix the whitespace. The easiest way to do this is to paste your code into your answer, then select it and click on the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K.